# select box (dropdown list) to load theme script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

i'm using highchart and want to use a select list for loading themes. the theme are `.js` files. i want to acheave something like that:

```
<select id="theme">
<option value="">Default</option>
<option value="js/theme/theme1.js">theme1</option>
<option value="js/theme/theme2.js">theme2</option>
</select>
```

in other words, how can i change the `src=""` tag of the `<script></script>` in the head of my html using select box!!

thank you!!

Comment: It is not possible to change the src attribute of an existing <script> element in the DOM :)

Comment: What the javascript in those files does?

Comment: Even if you change the *src*, the last loaded script will still work.

Comment: @BojanPetkovski Can i change the scripts src from the console ?

Comment: can i do $("#theme").on('change', function () {
    $('script').attr('src', $(this).val());
});  ??

Comment: @TusharRaj You can change the src but the first loaded script will still work because it is already loaded. You can create dynamically another script element and add the src attribute but it depends what are you trying to achieve :) And in your example you need to target which script you want to change the src, like you have it it will change all script src attributes that are on your page :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give option of different themes to your users you need to include all highchart theme js scripts in your html. All highcharts theme js files do this:

```
Highcharts.theme = {
colors: ["#DDDF0D", "#55BF3B", "#DF5353", "#7798BF", "#aaeeee", "#ff0066", "#eeaaee",
"#55BF3B", "#DF5353", "#7798BF", "#aaeeee"],....
....
var highchartsOptions = Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);
```

so when you include a js file, it changes the theme of the highcharts.

You can edit these theme js files and change the names of the settings as `Highcharts.themeDarkBlue = { .....`, `Highcharts.themeLightBlue = { .....`, etc. Then when your user makes a selection from the drop down you need to call whatever theme the user has selected as

```
Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.themeDarkBlue);
```

and re-populate the chart.

**Update:**

Can't really generate a fiddle for this so:

Your html:

```
.....
    <script src='themes/themeDarkBlue.js'></script>
    <script src='themes/themeLightBlue.js'></script>
    <script src='themes/themeBlack.js'></script>
.... //more theme references
```

In your `themes` folder you have three js files, themeDarkBlue.js, themeLightBlue.js and themeBlack.js

Your themeDarkBlue.js content:

```
var darkBlueTheme = {colors: ["#DDDF0D", "#55BF3B", "#DF5353", "#7798B"....};
```

Your themeLightBlue.js content:

```
var lightBlueTheme = {colors: ["#xxxF0D", "#xxxF3B", "#DF5353", "#7798B"....};
```

Inside your html:

```
$("#themeDropDown").change(function(){
   if ($(this).val() = 'Dark Blue'){
      Hightcharts.setOptions(darkBlueTheme);
   }
   else if ($(this).val() = 'Light Blue'){
      Hightcharts.setOptions(lightBlueTheme);
   }
   //else if 'Black'
   repopulateHighChart();
});
```

This should be clear enough.

Comment: so this means i have to past all the theme script inside the `Highcharts.theme ={}` i fi want to use 3 or 4 different themes my html will be like 5000 line ??

Comment: No, you'll just reference different scripts. i.e. `<script src='blueTheme.js'></script> <script src='darkBlueTheme.js'></script>` in your html. Then edit the js files as I mentioned so themes have different names. So your html won't be 5000 lines, you'll just reference 5 different js files.

Comment: Sorry but stil don't get it. is there any way to have an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: thank you but still couldn't get work. i set a jsfiddel example. please help me to edit it and get it working [link](http://jsfiddle.net/oxuy09hd/1/)

Comment: if i get i should declare all the themes in the head then edit each theme file and change `highchartsOptions = Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme)` to `highchartsOptions = Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.themename)` use the theme name as value in my select menu. right ?

Comment: When you edit the theme js files you don't need the line `highchartsOptions = Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.themename)` at the bottom of them. Drop down values don't matter. Name them whatever you want, you just need to handle the different drop down values in your change handler. You can put the option 'very ugly, ugh!` in your drop down, then you need to modify the `if` inside your `change` handler, i.e. 'if ($(this).val() == 'very ugly, ugh!') { Highcharts.setOptions(blackTheme);}'

Comment: still something missing. i'll try to resume:

Comment: still something missing. i'll try to resume: 1-edit the them files (add var highchart.themename). 2-add my themes to the <head>. 3-use if inside change functon according to my theme ($('#theme')....

Comment: Inside your change function you use the id of the dropdown, not the name of the theme.

Comment: yes i'm using the select dropdown id wich is id=theme. but still can't get it work...when i select an option nothing happen. even the chart doesn't reload.

Comment: Chart won't reload only because you reset its options, you need to implement the method `repopulateHighChart()` yourself to re-draw the chart.

Comment: thank you so much artm...but nothing works. i'm lost